StrongSwan VPN Interface Issue
I need help understanding interfaces in Linux. I set up a StrongSwan VPN. The client asked for a specific subnet so I created a virtual interface called eth0:1. The LAN interface is eth1.
In the ipsec.conf I configured the below:
leftid= LAN Interface
Left Subnet= customer requested subnet
I have two rules in FORWARD rules in IPTable
1st rule: src subnet customer requested to dst  customer private subnet    allow
2nd rule = src customer requested subnet dst subnet customer requested     allow
This should allow traffic from my private subnet to the customer private subnet, however, the customer also has the LAN IP (LEFTID listed above).
VPN traffic coming from the customer end will hit eth1 (LAN IP) first then forward to eth0:1 (subnet customer requested). However, this is not happening and I'm not sure how to set up routing on this Ubuntu server.
I have another VPN in the same setup but that works perfectly fine. The issue here is: the customer cannot ping my internal subnet on eth0:1. I cannot ping their side either but they have pings disabled.
How would I go about setting up routing for the VPN tunnel, so any traffic from the customer is routed to the correct interface, and the interface can respond back via the VPN tunnel.
I'm new to using StrongSwan so any help would be appreciated
